# glutsolidsphere, lighteffect around the sphere

Tags: c++, c, opengl, geometry, glut

I´m writing a game in C/C++ in which you can move a ball. I´ve created the ball with glutsolidsphere. Now I want to create "a ring of light" around it like the suns corona. I´ve read something about GL_EMISSION as material. But is this possible? And what other possiblities do i have?

Could you maybe give me a short example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general, questions asking for code examples or pointers to off-site resources are not considered good questions here. (As you can see, you've already got 1 close vote for your question.) Please post the code you're having trouble with and ask specific questions about that code. Let us know what you've tried and what hasn't worked for you and we can better help you.

Comment: There is not such thing as C/C++...